# Can't download any results from Show-ListView

Tags: powershell, module

I've written a script to generate a report that allows downloading a list of pages and relevant tags applied to them (within a section). In that script, I wrote the below code to download the output. For some reason, any export buttons, that Show-ListView displays, do nothing. files can't be downloaded. What is the reason for not given to download the results from Show-ListView?

```
    $options = @{
    "News" = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/News"
    "Assets" = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Assets"
    "Industries" = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Industries"
    "Solutions" = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Solutions"
    "Succes" = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Customer Success"
    "Partners" = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Partners"
}

$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="selectedOption"; Title="Choose an option"; Options=$options; Tooltip="Choose one."}
    )
    Title = "Option selector"
    Description = "Choose the right option."
    Width = 300
    Height = 300
    ShowHints = $true
}

$result = Read-Variable @props
if($result -ne "ok") {
    Exit
}

$table = New-Object System.Data.Datatable;


$path1 = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/News"
$path2 = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Assets"
$path3 = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Industries"
$path4 = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Solutions"
$path5 = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Customer Success"
$path6 = "/sitecore/content/IFS/IFS/Home/Partners"
 
if($selectedOption -eq $path1){
    $allitems = Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "$path//*[@@TemplateName = 'Article']"  
}elseif($selectedOption -eq $path2 ){
    $allitems = Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "$path//*[@@TemplateName = 'Asset']"
}elseif($selectedOption -eq $path3){
    $allitems = Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "$path//*[@@TemplateName = 'Content Page']"
}elseif($selectedOption -eq $path4){
    $allitems = Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "$path//*[@@TemplateName = 'Content Page']"
}elseif($selectedOption -eq $path5){
    $allitems = Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "$path//*[@@TemplateName = 'Customer Story']"
}elseif($selectedOption -eq $path6){
    $allitems = Get-Item -Path master:// -Query "$path//*[@@TemplateName = 'Partner Profile']"
}

[void]$table.Columns.Add("Name")
[void]$table.Columns.Add("Tag_Category")
[void]$table.Columns.Add("Tags")
ForEach ($item in $allItems) {
    $name = $item.DisplayName
    [void]$table.Rows.Add("$name","","")
    $rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["CardCategory"]
    $selectedItems = $rawIds.GetItems()
    foreach($selectedItem in $selectedItems){
        $tag = $selectedItem.DisplayName
        [void]$table.Rows.Add("","CardCategory","$tag")
    }

    $rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["ContentType"]
    $selectedItems = $rawIds.GetItems()
    foreach($selectedItem in $selectedItems){
        $tag = $selectedItem.DisplayName
        [void]$table.Rows.Add("","ContentType","$tag")
    }
    
    
    $rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["Industry"]
    $selectedItems = $rawIds.GetItems()
    foreach($selectedItem in $selectedItems){
        $tag = $selectedItem.DisplayName
        [void]$table.Rows.Add("","Industry","$tag")
    }
    
    $rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["Language"]
    $selectedItems = $rawIds.GetItems()
    foreach($selectedItem in $selectedItems){
        $tag = $selectedItem.DisplayName
        [void]$table.Rows.Add("","Language","$tag")
    }
    
    $rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["ProductCategory"]
    $selectedItems = $rawIds.GetItems()
    foreach($selectedItem in $selectedItems){
        $tag = $selectedItem.DisplayName
        [void]$table.Rows.Add("","ProductCategory","$tag")
    }
    
    $rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["Region"]
    $selectedItems = $rawIds.GetItems()
    foreach($selectedItem in $selectedItems){
        $tag = $selectedItem.DisplayName
        [void]$table.Rows.Add("","Region","$tag")
    }
    
    $rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$item.Fields["Topic"]
    $selectedItems = $rawIds.GetItems()
    foreach($selectedItem in $selectedItems){
        $tag = $selectedItem.DisplayName
        [void]$table.Rows.Add("","Topic","$tag")
    }
}

$table | Show-ListView -Property Name, Tag_category, Tags
```

[image]

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any errors in logs when you click to download?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors. But the export buttons are not working.

Comment: It's commonly a configuration problem. The docs outline which services need to be enabled for downloading to work.

Comment: I believe it's the Handle Download service. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/security#service-descriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this conversation here on github as @WulfgarDK is saying above - https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/912

But this was not the reason in our case.

We had the same issue and solution was to enable `Spe.IdentityServer.config` at `\inetpub\wwwroot\website\App_Config\Include\Spe`.

OOTB this file comes with `Sitecore Powershell` module as `disabled`. Just need to remove .disabled from the config name.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This works for me